# For $T $ a continuous, linear, open map there exists a $C$ such that $||x|| \le C||Tx|| $

Tags: functional-analysis

As stated in the title, let be a $T $ a continuous, linear, open map from a normed space $X$ onto a normed space $Y $. I would like to know if it is true that there exists a constant $C$ such that for any $x \in X, \ \ ||x||_X \le C||Tx||_Y $.

I tried to verify it but got stuck. Is the claim true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, if such a constant exists, we must have $C>0$. And $T$ must be injective; otherwise, there will be a non-zero vector $x$ such that $Tx=0$ and so $\lVert x\rVert>C\lVert Tx\rVert=0$.

On the other hand, suppose now that $T$ *is* injective. Since $T$ is open and linear [it is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2101897/446262). So, since $T$ is injective too, it has an inverse. Let $C=\lVert T^{-1}\rVert$. Then$$\lVert x\rVert=\bigl\lVert T^{-1}(Tx)\bigr\rVert\leqslant C\lVert Tx\rVert.$$

So, such a constant $C$ exits if and only if $T$ is injective.

Comment: Now, you are **not** being dense. I did not express myself clearly. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: Done. What do you think now?

Comment: Looks good!  ${}$